MAUI CommunityToolkit Popup raises error with SetShadowView
In my .NET8 MAUI application, I use the MAUI CommunityToolkit version 9.0.1. I have an issue with the Popup that crashes my app. I saw a bug on GitHub that is exactly my issue but there is no answer for it.
I defined my Popup view
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup
        x:Class="LanguageInUse.Views.Popups.LoadingPopup"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:LanguageInUse"
        xmlns:popups="clr-namespace:LanguageInUse.Views.Popups"
        xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit">

    <toolkit:Popup.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type popups:LoadingPopup}">
            <Setter Property="Size" Value="300,300" />
            <Setter Property="Color" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup" Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </toolkit:Popup.Resources>

    <StackLayout
            Margin="30"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            WidthRequest="350">
        <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <ActivityIndicator
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    IsRunning="True"
                    Color="{StaticResource Gray900}" />
            <Label
                    x:Name="labelLoading"
                    MaximumWidthRequest="240"
                    Style="{StaticResource labelLoading}"
                    Text="{lang:Translate Loading}"
                    WidthRequest="240" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</toolkit:Popup>

When my app is in Release mode and it displays the popup on iOS, I get this error

CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Views.MauiPopup.SetShadowView(UIView&
target)
CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Views.MauiPopup.ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowException(IntPtr )
UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Int32 , String[] , IntPtr ,
IntPtr ) UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String[] , Type , Type )
LanguageInUse.Program.Main(String[] args)

To display the Popup, I use this line
var loadingPopup = new LoadingPopup();
loadingPopup.SetMessage(AppResources.DictionaryWordsLoading);
loadingPopup.Opened += async (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        // my code
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (loadingPopup != null)
            await loadingPopup.CloseAsync();
    }
};
await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(loadingPopup);
loadingPopup = null;

How can I fix it?

It sounds like the fix will be included in the next release

Thanks for your feedback. You may follow the issue [BUG] Popup crashes the app on iOS and get the latest updates.
